# C++/Address Space: 2 Bytes per adress?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

I was just trying something and i was wondering how this could be. I have the following Code:

```
int var1 = 132;

int var2 = 200;

int *secondvariable = &var2;

cout << *(secondvariable+2) << endl << sizeof(int) << endl;
```

I get the Output

132

4

So how is it possible that the second int is only 2 addresses higher? I mean shouldn't it be 4 addresses? I'm currently under WIN10 x64.

Regards

Comment: Actualy `secondvariable+2` is `2*sizeof(int) `=8 bytes higher

Comment: @Oliv Typically at least - there are systems out there where `sizeof(int) != 4`...

Answer (score 7):

With `cout << *(secondvariable+2)` you don't print a pointer, you print the *value* at `secondvariable[2]`, which is an invalid indexing and lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you want to print a pointer then drop the dereference and print `secondvariable+2`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `secondvariable+2` also has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

While you already are far in the field of undefined behaviour (see [Some programmer dude](http://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/52275540/1312382)) due to indexing an array out of bounds (a single variable is considered an array of length 1 for such matters), some technical background:

Alignment! Compilers are allowed to place variables at addresses such that they can be accessed most efficiently. As you ***seem*** to have gotten valid output by adding `2*sizeof(int)` to the second variable's address, you apparently have reached the first one *by accident*. Apparently, the compiler decided to leave a gap in between the two variables so that both can be aligned to addresses dividable by 8.

Be aware, though, that you don't have any guarantee for such alignment, different compilers might decide differently (or same compiler on another system), and alignment even might be changed via compiler flags.

On the other hand, *arrays* are guaranteed to occupy contiguous memory, so you would have gotten the expected result in the following example:

```
int array[2];

int* a0 = &array[0];
int* a1 = &array[1];

uintptr_t diff = static_cast<uintptr_t>(a1) - static_cast<uintptr_t>(a0);
std::cout << diff;
```

The cast to `uintptr_t` (or alternatively to `char*`) assures that you get address difference in bytes, not sizes of `int`...

Answer (score 0):

This is not how C++ works.

You can't "navigate" your scope like this.

Such pointer antics have completely undefined behaviour and shall not be relied upon.

You are not punching holes in tape now, you are writing a description of a program's semantics, that gets converted by your compiler into something executable by a machine.

Code to these abstractions and everything will be fine.